# Type Error: () got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, jinja2

I'm having trouble figuring out where my function `editMenuItem()` is getting the unknown keyword argument `restaurant_id` from. I've searched through similar questions and cannot find a solution. If anyone has any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate them.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: editMenuItem() got an unexpected keyword argument 'restaurant_id'
```

`editMenuItem()`

```
### Edit a menu item. ###
@app.route('/restaurant/<int:restaurant_id>/menu/<int:menuitem_id>/edit/',
            methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def editMenuItem(menuitem_id):
    menuitem = session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(id=menuitem_id).one()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['newname']:
            menuitem.name = request.form['newname']
        if request.form['newdescription']:
            menuitem.description = request.form['newdescription']
        if request.form['newprice']:
            menuitem.description = request.form['newprice']
        session.add(menuitem)
        session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('showMenu', restaurant_id=menuitem.restaurant_id))
    else:
        return render_template('editMenuItem.html', menuitem=menuitem)
```

`Relevant html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="six columns">
    <form action="{{ url_for('editMenuItem', menuitem_id = menuitem.id) }}" method="post">
      <div class="six columns">
        <div class="six columns">
          Menu Item ID : {{ menuitem.id  }}
          <br>
          Menu Item Name : {{ menuitem.name }}
          <br>
          Menu Item Description : {{ menuitem.description }}
          <br>
          Menu ITem Price : {{ menuitem.price }}
          <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="six columns">
          <div class="six columns">
            <label for="newItemName">New item name</label>
            <input type="text" id="newname" class="form" name="newname" placeholder="Enter new name here">
            <br>
          </div>
          <div class="six columns">
            <label for="newItemDescription">New item Description</label>
            <input type="text" id="newdescription" class="form" name="newdescription" placeholder="Enter new description here">
            <br>
          </div>
          <div class="six columns">
            <label for="newItemPrice">New item Price</label>
            <input type="text" id="newprice" class="form" name="newprice" placeholder="Enter new price here">
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
          <button type="submit" class="button">Edit</button>
          <a href="{{ url_for('showMenu') }}" class="button">Cancel</a>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm not sure where this keyword argument is coming from as the `restaurant_id` should not be necessary to give in order for my function to work. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Where does `menuitem_id` come from? Hint: it is the same for `restaurant_id`.

Comment: The only thing I can see is the url used for my `@app.route` Would this be where my function is drawing the argument from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Wombatz hint I was able to solve the problem by altering my `editMenuItem` function and changing the necessary template.

Updated function:

```
### Edit a menu item. ###
@app.route('/restaurant/<int:restaurant_id>/menu/<int:menuitem_id>/edit/',
            methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def editMenuItem(menuitem_id, restaurant_id):
    menuitem = session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(id=menuitem_id).one()
    restaurant = session.query(Restaurant).filter_by(id=restaurant_id).one()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['newname']:
            menuitem.name = request.form['newname']
        if request.form['newdescription']:
            menuitem.description = request.form['newdescription']
        if request.form['newprice']:
            menuitem.description = request.form['newprice']
        session.add(menuitem)
        session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('showMenu', restaurant_id=menuitem.restaurant_id))
    else:
        return render_template('editMenuItem.html', menuitem=menuitem, restaurant=restaurant)
```

Updated template:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('editMenuItem', menuitem_id = menuitem.id, restaurant_id = restaurant.id) }}" method="post">

<a href="{{ url_for('showMenu', restaurant_id=menuitem.restaurant_id) }}" class="button">Cancel</a>
```

I'm new to using this site so I'm not sure if I can "upvote" your comment Wombatz, but thanks for the hint.